# How to clear and set high 8 bits of ULONG

Tags: c

Straight to the point. I want to change higher 8 bits of a variable.

```
ULONG parameters;
```

I can get them like that:

```
(parameters >> 24) & 0xFF
```

But I'm not really sure how can I clear the value there and set my own.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set multiple bits in one line in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21786843/how-to-set-multiple-bits-in-one-line-in-c)

Comment: Your posted code indicates that a 'ULONG' is 32 bits.  That may or may not be true.  a reasonable method to get the number of bits is: `ULONG myvar;  unsigned numBits = sizeof (ULONG) * 8`  In any case, one method to clear the upper bits is: then: `myvar &= (ULONG)(0x00 << (numBits -8);`  to set those bits to a specific value, first clear them, then: `myvar |= (ULONG)(theValue) << (numBits -8);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to clear those bits and set them to zero:

```
parameters &= 0x00ffffff;    // (mask for bits [0, 24)
```

Alternatively let's say you have a mask for those upper 8-bits:

```
enum {bitmask = 0xff000000}; // (mask for bits [24, 32)
```

You can likewise clear those upper 8-bits (bits `[24, 32)` or `[24, 31]`) using the complement of the mask:

```
parameters &= ~bitmask; // (~0xff000000 == 0x00ffffff)
```

Using a bitwise complement might seem wasteful here if you can avoid it but typically optimizers are more than smart enough to eliminate it if `bitmask` is known at compile-time. If you want to set bits in the range, `[24, 32)` to `some_value` then:

```
parameters &= ~bitmask;           // clear bits [24, 32)
parameters |= (some_value << 24); // shift some_value to occupy
                                  // bits [24, 32) and combine the
                                  // bits.
```

Note that `some_value` should have a range that fits in 8-bits. We're basically left-shifting those 8 bits to occupy bits `[24, 32)`. Then the `bitwise or` combines the bits which, after clearing those upper 8 bits, has the effect of setting them to that value. Then you can pull the value back out again using:

```
some_value = (parameter >> 24);
```

You don't actually need to do a `bitwise and` here with `0xff` if you can guarantee that `parameter` is 32-bit or that any bits beyond bit 32 will not be used/set. Otherwise:

```
some_value = (parameter >> 24) & 0xff;
```

Or if you have that bitmask handy:

```
some_value = (parameter & bitmask) >> 24;
```

Often it can be handy to define both a mask and shift value, like so:

```
enum
{
     shift = 24,
     bitmask = 0xff000000, // mask for bits [24, 32)
};
```

Then you can generalize this to:

```
// fetching some value:
some_value = (parameter & bitmask) >> shift;

// setting some value:
parameter = (parameter & ~bitmask) | (some_value << shift);
```

And that works regardless as long as you set the bitmask and shift value. If you want to set bits in the range: `[8, 24)` (16-bits) then we simply do:

```
enum
{
     shift = 8,
     bitmask = 0x00ffff00, // mask for bits [8, 24)
};
```

And the code above should work just fine.

Answer (score 3):

You can clear the high 8 bits with:

```
value &= 0x00FFFFFF;
```

Note that the 00 is not actually needed, it's just there for clarity. And if you want to set all of the high 8 bits:

```
value |= 0xFF000000;
```

Comment: But how to set it to specific value? Assign a value to it.